# Преобразование массивов для работы с гистограммой

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Я столкнулся с небольшой проблемой при построении гистограммы в mathplot. 
У меня есть файл, в котором данные в одну строку разделённые через запятую.
Я хочу прочесть данные и построить гистограмму но так, чтобы каждый столб был своего цвета. Но когда я читаю файл - у меня получается один массив формата [a,b,c...]
Histogram же для построения, чтобы у каждого столбца был свой цвет, просто на вход [[a],[b],[c],...]
Поэтому я попытался просто создать ещё один массив уже в требуемом виде
код

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
# data = loadtxt('Music.dat') Я читаю файл, после чтения получаю результат как в следующей строке
data =  [105, 200, 310, 99, 286]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3 = axes.flatten()    


labels = 'Grunge', 'Hip Hop', 'Metal', 'Schlager music', 'Rock'
bins = np.linspace(50, 400, 20)
colors = ['red', 'black', 'orange', 'green', 'tan']
ax1.hist([[105], [200], [310], [99], [286]], bins, density=True, histtype='bar', color=colors, 
label=labels)
ax1.legend(prop={'size': 2})
ax1.set_title('Histogram with legend')
```

В этом случае (вручную введённые откорректированные данные) у меня получается ровно то, что я хочу - 5 столбцов разного цвета.

Я попытался преобразовать массив следующим образом

```
data_mod=np.zeros(shape=(5,1)) 
for x in range (0, 5):
   data_mod[x]=[data[x]]
```

Но при выведении массива на экран print(data_mod) я получаю следующий результат:

```
[[105.]
 [200.]
 [310.]
 [ 99.]
 [286.]]
[105. 200. 310.  99. 286.]
```

т.е. как я понимаю, массив автоматически преобразуется.

В связи с этим мой вопрос:
как мне максимально безболезненно преобразовать [105, 200, 310, 99, 286] в [[105] [200] [310] [ 99] [286]] и почему не работает мой метод?
Возможно есть другой метод, заставить гистограмм покрасить каждый столбец в свой цвет, без столь неудобного преобразования?

Comment: можете выложить файл с данными на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: И это можно заменить все на data = [[x] for x in data], где data - ваш массив цифр

Comment: @Nobody Да, спасибо, именно это я и искал! Оформите как ответ, чтобы я вопрос закрыл?

Comment: @MaxU в этом нет никакого смысла, т.к. на текущий момент в файле всего 5 данных как в коде. Я просто разбираюсь с построением графиков и пробую различные варианты постройки. Ну и на вопрос уже ответили.

Comment: Нет никакого смысла строить гистограммы для столбцов, состоящих из единственного элемента;) Разбираться лучше используя правдоподобные данные

Comment: Это я понимаю, но мне был интересен именно вариант, можно ли преобразовать данные так, чтобы они считались за множество различных, чтобы построить разноцветную гистограмму, а не одного цвета

Comment: Обязательно учтите - [как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания массива массивов в которые входит по одному числу подойдёт *list comprehension*. Для этого достаточно `data = [[x] for x in data]`, где data - одномерный массив с данными

Answer (score 3):

Если суть вопроса сводится к тому как преобразовать Numpy вектор в 2D матрицу, состоящую из одного столбца, то делается это обычно так:

```
arr = np.array(data)       #  данная строка нужна если данные не являются Numpy вектором
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 1)
```

---

```
In [4]: arr
Out[4]:
array([[105],
       [200],
       [310],
       [ 99],
       [286]])

In [5]: arr.shape
Out[5]: (5, 1)
```

Но для подобных задач, я бы использовал модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) - он идеально подходит для чтения/записи, обработки и визуализации табличных данных. Под капотом он использует тот же Numpy, но гораздо богаче его по функционалу.

PS если бы в вопросе был приведен пример более правдоподобных данных, то и в ответе я бы привел полностью рабочий пример от чтения данных до построения гистограмм.

Comment: Да, такое решение ещё более элегантное. Спасибо!
Про Pandas - учту.